# Limit proof using delta epsilon

Tags: calculus

I've tried to figure out a way to use what was given below to prove what follows but i'm unsure of what approach to take.

given $$ \lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=5$$

use the delta epsilon limit definition to show that

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} f(2x+1)=5 $$

Comment: Hint: what is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} 2x + 1$?

Comment: could you expand?  I'm not sure why you would do this

Comment: How have you written the delta-epsilon limit definition? It is quite straightforward from there.

Comment: @johnfowles since you know that $\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 1} f(y) = 5$, that means for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is a $\delta' \gt 0$ such that $|f(y) - 5| \lt \epsilon$ when $|y - 1| \lt \delta'$. But since $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}2x + 1 = 1$, we can choose a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|2x + 1 - 1| \lt \delta'$ when $|x| \lt \delta$. Then $|f(2x + 1) - 5| = |f(y) - 5| \lt \epsilon$ when $|x| \lt \delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=5$, where exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $\vert 1-y\vert<\delta$ we have $\vert 5-f(y)\vert <\varepsilon$. Then if $\vert y\vert <\delta/2$, we have $\vert 1-(2y+1)\vert < \delta$, and so $\vert 5-f(2y+1)\vert < \varepsilon$, completing the proof.

Comment: I completely missed the obvious.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If $\varepsilon > 0$, by assumption there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-5| < \varepsilon$ if $|x-1| < \delta$. Note that $\xi \mapsto 2\xi + 1 =: x$ is a bijection; so $|x-1| < \delta$ iff $|\xi| < \delta/2$, and $|f(x)-5| = |f(2\xi + 1) - 5| < \varepsilon$.